# Injector.getInstance(..) returns a new instance for a singleton

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

My Module:

```
bind( Translator.class ).to( TranslatorImpl.class ).in( Scopes.SINGLETON );
```

Now I expect to get the same instance everytime when I do

```
Injector injector = ...;
injector.getInstance( Translator.class );
```

But if I do

```
injector.getInstance( TranslatorImpl.class );
```

I get a new instance everytime. Is this a bug or expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour because `TranslatorImpl.class` isn't bound to the singleton scope, only `Translator.class` is.

If you want both `getInstance(..)` to return the same instance, you could bind the implementation to the singleton scope:

```
bind(Translator.class).to(TranslatorImpl.class);
bind(TranslatorImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
assertEquals(injector.getInstance(Translator.class), injector.getInstance(TranslatorImpl.class));
```

See https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#applying-scopes for more details.